# Probability that amoeba population dies out completely - why can't the probability be 1?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider an amoeba. At each iteration, it can split into 2, 3 amoebas, stay the same, or die. These 4 events occur with equal probability.

Let $E$ denote the event that all current amoeba dies, and $F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4$ denote the above 4 events, then we have

\begin{align}
    P(E) = P(E|F_1)P(F_1) + P(E|F_2)P(F_2) + P(E|F_3)P(F_3) + P(E|F_4)P(F_4) \\
    P(F_i) = \frac{1}{4} \\
    P(E|F_1) = 1 \\
    P(E|F_2) = P(E)^2 \\
    P(E|F_3) = P(E)^3 \\
    P(E|F_4) = P(E) \\
    P(E) = \frac{1}{4}[1 + P(E) + P(E)^2 + P(E)^3] \\
\end{align}

Solving this cubic, we find $P(E) = 1, 1 \pm \sqrt{2}$. We throw out the negative root, and we are left with $P(E) = 1, \sqrt{2} - 1$. In the book I am reading, it restricts the probabilities to $P(E) < 1$.

But intuitively, I do not understand why $P(E) = 1$ isn't possible. Can someone intuitively explain this?

In addition, using $P(E) = \sqrt{2} - 1$, does this mean that the expectation of the number of iterations that the amoeba population dies out is infinity?

---

One thought that occurred to me is that the expected number of amoeba after one iteration is $0.25(1 + 2 + 3 + 0) = 1.5$, and by induction we see that this continues to grow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On average one amoeba produces $1.5$ the next round, so if there are a large number of them the probability of extinction is very small.  This shows you can't have extinction with probability $1$.

Comment: I just edited into the OP what I think is what you stated. If on average one amoeba produces $< 1$ in the next round, would that make probability of 1 feasible and any probability $< 1$ not feasible?

Comment: @David:  that is correct.  They would die out with probability $1$ even though it is theoretically possible they could go on forever.

Comment: So in the current case, what would be the expected number of turns until all the amoeba population dies out? It seems it's unbounded, so it becomes infinity?

Comment: Yes, the expected number is undefined because you expect it (sometimes) never to go extinct and you can't put that into the average.